# Can't loop over array containing data points

Tags: python

I have a problem. In my Python program, I have the following code:

```
lines = []

for x in range(2):
    lines.append(probabilistic_hough_line(image, threshold=2, theta=tested_angles, line_length=0, line_gap=int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(np.square(image.shape[0]) + np.square(image.shape[1]))))))
    
print(lines)
```

Now this returns me:

```
[[((24, 143), (24, 143)), ((331, 873), (108, 360)), ((327, 909), (185, 551)), ((308, 1023), (122, 447)), ((292, 962), (292, 962)), ((240, 798), (240, 798)), ((215, 762), (215, 762)), ((72, 158), (72, 158)), ((17, 96), (17, 96)), ((223, 793), (151, 515)), ((175, 588), (175, 588)), ((11, 4), (11, 4)), ((129, 434), (129, 434)), ((345, 1038), (19, 100)), ((246, 801), (246, 801)), ((236, 749), (236, 749)), ((248, 824), (30, 143)), ((99, 180), (99, 180)), ((363, 1135), (361, 1131)), ((197, 597), (158, 503)), ((106, 365), (6, 64)), ((358, 1107), (142, 470)), ((139, 487), (139, 487)), ((45, 249), (45, 249)), ((205, 721), (90, 285)), ((317, 969), (21, 103)), ((124, 464), (124, 464)), ((329, 878), (329, 878)), ((348, 1043), (348, 1043)), ((194, 613), (194, 613)), ((238, 776), (76, 224)), ((221, 795), (221, 795)), ((97, 181), (97, 181)), ((112, 380), (112, 380)), ((48, 250), (48, 250)), ((179, 544), (179, 544)), ((117, 422), (70, 187)), ((277, 845), (277, 845)), ((135, 461), (135, 461)), ((217, 762), (217, 762)), ((9, 32), (9, 32)), ((32, 145), (32, 145)), ((34, 164), (34, 164)), ((244, 807), (244, 807)), ((155, 565), (155, 565)), ((225, 782), (225, 782)), ((209, 757), (209, 757)), ((231, 714), (231, 714)), ((337, 907), (337, 907)), ((119, 417), (119, 417)), ((250, 819), (250, 819)), ((284, 941), (284, 941)), ((147, 536), (147, 536)), ((299, 941), (299, 941)), ((305, 988), (287, 932)), ((42, 223), (42, 223)), ((268, 902), (268, 902)), ((322, 910), (322, 910)), ((270, 887), (270, 887)), ((260, 834), (260, 834)), ((289, 942), (289, 942)), ((56, 335), (56, 335)), ((211, 755), (168, 611)), ((183, 515), (183, 515)), ((273, 920), (273, 920)), ((104, 341), (104, 341)), ((4, 74), (4, 74))]]
```

Then I want to loop over all the points, so I have this loop:

```
for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in lines:
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I hope this code is enough to help me, but if more code is needed, just take a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/programmatic-identification-of-support-resistance-trend-lines-with-python-d797a4a90530). All code I use in this page! Can someone help me what I am doing wrong in the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the double brackets at the beginning and end of your print output. You have a list inside a list, and that inner list contains your tuple-pairs.

The for loop loops over the outer list, and the first (and only) item it gets is the inner list.

Now, it tries to unpack that list's items into `x0`, `x1`, `y1`, and `y2`. That makes four variables in two pairs. So, the loop needs two tuples containing two values each.

But you are giving it many more tuples - remember, it tries to unpack from the inner list, instead of from each tuple inside that inner list.

To solve this, either go directly over the inner list:

```py
for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in lines[0]:
```

or, if you cannot be sure that there will be always, ***always*** just *one* inner list in the outer list, use a nested loop:

```
for line in lines:
    for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in line:
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in lines[0]:
```

points seem to be inside a list inside the 'lines' list

Answer (score 1):

Just index 0 from the data.
Example:

```
data = [[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8))]]

for (x0, y0), (x1, y1) in data[0]:
```